# Adobe InDesign ; How to hide all text - except a couple of sentences?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I need to extract some text from InDesign - but the only way I know is cut and paste into another document. Is there a way - like inverted conditional text, where I can hide everything except some sentences?

Example: I have a document that is 100 pages long and on some pages, there is text that I need to keep visible. So I need to hide 90+ pages with different text layers etc. except some text.

Comment: With so little information, it really is hard to advise. Does the text that you want to extract have a style applied to it? Does it have something specific? Please provide screenshots as well...

Comment: Is this a permanent change, or do you need to be able to get the hidden text back so that it can be read again?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for little information, but I found a solution. 
I used find and replace - choose all text in a certain colour, and replace with "conditional text". Then all I was left with was the text I wanted to use further. I was then free to hide and unhide text.

I could not use layers. Because some text I wanted to hide was in the same textbox. Anyhow - find and replace works!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide layers and individual elements through the layers panel.
Pages and parts of elements can not be hidden.

You can choose what to export to PDF as well. By right clicking the layer > layer options and remove the check next to print layer. And by selecting what pages to export in the export dialogue.